# plot large graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a graph with more than 5000 nodes in Matlab.
I'm using biograph and view function for this command but after some executing Matlab show this error:

> The layout engine cannot generate this graph,
>   try other layout types or reduce the number of nodes.

I'm try other layout types but give me same error.

Comment: is `gplot` an alternative?

Comment: May be you can plot some of your data, say, every third element (`plot(x(1:3:end),y(1:3:end))`). If you have large amount of data to plot, it should be no noticeable difference

Comment: thank you @Daniel and @Mikhail Genkin , `gplot` need to set coordinates of nodes and i can't do this. 5000 nodes is downsampled from very bigger dataset. is there another way to plot this data with other softwares?